# Access non-https-image-links in fully https secured magento store

Tags: magento-1.9, https, m2e

I have a webshop which is fully secured over https.

Since this shop uses the M2E extension and the eBay part of this extension only accepts non-https-links for images, I need to be able to access images with both url variations, http and https.

Anybody has a solution for this?

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution now.

Introduced a subdomain like ebay.mydomain.de.
Copied following file to locale and changed it:

```
M2ePro / Model / Magento / Product.php
```

about line 1228 change code to:

Warning: use your-normal-domain with http even if it is https since m2e always want to use http

```
return str_replace(array('http://your-normal-domain', ' '), array('http://your-ebay-subdomain', '%20'), $url);
```